Unable to find gradle-8.6-all.zip in React Native
I'm developing a mobile application using React Native, and when I run the react-native run-android command, I encounter the following error:
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\omers\OneDrive\Desktop\react_native\mymobileapp\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-8.6-all.zip (Sistem belirtilen dosyay� bulam�yor) at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:213) at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:152) at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106) at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:84) at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:180) at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:129) at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:109) at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.forceFetch(Install.java:171) at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.fetchDistribution(Install.java:104) at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:46) at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:81) at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:68) at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69) at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:68) at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:102) at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:66).

This error indicates that Gradle cannot find the gradle-8.6-all.zip file. However, when I check the file path, I can see that the file exists.
I have updated the distributionUrl in the gradle-wrapper.properties file to gradle-8.6-all.zip.
I have checked my internet connection and verified that there are no issues.
I have tried running CMD as an administrator, but the issue persists.
What can I do to resolve this issue?
Environment:

Windows 10
React Native
Gradle 8.6


Developing inside OneDrive folder isn't a good idea, that will cause problems according to what others reported here. reboot your system and move the mentioned gradle zip to trash (if something goes wrong you can still restore it). It should be redownloaded next time you execute gradlew.

It's a gradle bug in react-native. Go to folder android/gradle and modify the file gradle-wrapper.properties
Need change the version of gradle 8.6 to 8.5:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-all.zip

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-all.zip

